# Testing NAT Breakthrough Code

Tags: c#, networking, nat

I am very interested in at least trying to implement NAT break through for my senior project.
(I am doing a networking API).
It's not even a requirement of my project, just a interest of mine.
I know the basics of how it works, correct me if I'm wrong:
Two clients connect to a server that isn't behind a NAT and this server, knowing the IP of these two clients, tell the clients to connect to each other at the same time. Thus the "Breakthrough".

This seems not terribly easy or terribly hard to code. 
However, the part I'm stuck at is the testing of this. Is there a reasonable setup I can do with just one router/one NAT and my three available computers?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I'd love to hear anyhting you learn about this.

Comment: I'll try to remember to come back here if/when I do it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of code/theory on NAT breaking, I cannot offer advice, but I can make some suggestions on setting up a test environment.

You can download a copy of [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/) and run it inside of a Virtual PC image (both free). This will give you a second router w/out purchasing any additional hardware. With this extra router, you can create a seperate subnet for your two clients.

Another, easier to grasp option is simply to pickup a second router, you can get a good one pretty cheap.

Then setup your existing router and server as they are now, a 192.168.1.x /24 subnet; then setup your second router (m0n0wall/hardware router) as 192.168.2.x /24 subnet, and plug the second router's "internet" port into one of the "PC" ports on your first router. Then plug both clients into the second router.

(I realize thats a bit confusing, comment if you cannot follow what I mean)

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I have this straight. You have two clients that are both behind NAT and a server that is not. Both clients connect to the server and are informed of the public facing IP address of the other. Since each now has a destination, they disconnect from the server and connect directly through their respective NAT boxes to each other. Is that your thinking? If so, I may have some bad news for you.

In order for this to work at all, you will have to have dedicated ports set up in each NAT configuration to forward at least one external port to a predefined internal IP address/port number. In a generic NAT setup outgoing connection requests will be captured by the NAT which will open a temporary external port. That external port number is used only for communications to that one originating address and port. When the connection is closed, that external port goes away and will be reassigned for another connection later. So if both clients talk to the server and then disconnect, the information the server sent them is now invalid.

Assuming you've worked around this somehow, it should be fairly easy to just connect both clients to the "internal" side of the NAT and the server PC to the "external" side. Then you have to hope that your NAT box is smart enough to loop back packets from one local external port to another. I'm sure that netfiler could be configured this way but I doubt a home internet "router" (e.g., Linksys, NetGear, etc.) would do it of the shelf.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I knew there was probably a lot of hurdles doing it on the same LAN. I may try to still do this but with my resources I should probably not make any promises to my professor huh?